# Invalid Cast Exception. Not sure why

Tags: vb.net, .net

Can anyone see from the following function why I would be getting an "Invalid Cast Exception"? More specifically this is the error "**Conversion from string "yyyyMMdd" to type 'Integer' is not valid.**"

I am trying to convert a DateTime value from the database to a String with the format "yyyyMMdd" so for example October 22, 1985 would be "19851022".

```
dbReader(fieldName).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Here is the entire function ...

```
Private Function GetDBReaderDateValue(ByVal dbReader As IDataReader, ByVal fieldName As String) As String

    If dbReader(fieldName) Is DBNull.Value Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return dbReader(fieldName).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fieldName` is not a DateTime, conversion will fail. Try to cast it to a Datetime first:

```
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParse(dbReader(fieldName).tostring, dt) Then
     Return dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
Else
     Throw New ArgumentException("GetDBReaderDateValue needs a Date-Column as parameter!")
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Date.TryParse be Date.TryParse(dbReader(fieldName).tostring, dt)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're calling `ToString` on an `Object`... and there's no overload that takes a `String` parameter. You probably need to cast to a `DateTime` first.